# Data Annotation/Validation and dynamic values

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, data-annotations

If some of my models have dynamic validation conditions (i.e. the string length can be minimum of 8 or 12 depending on a database value or some other dynamic value) is it impossible to use data annotation for validation?

From what I understand, the values of any parameter (example StringLength min/max value) have to be truly static. Are there alternatives for applications that have dynamic validation values?

Comment: If the validation changes through time your DataBase Data may not valid after sometime is it a good idea ?

Comment: @ali62b - I can safely assume it will always be valid since only administrators will have access to these values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your pretty much stuck with writing your own custom validationattribute:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validationattribute.aspx