# Data Annotations - How can I replace Range values with Web.Config values in MVC3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

How can I replace the Range values with Web.Config values in MVC3?

```
[Range(5, 20, ErrorMessage = "Initial Deposit should be between $5.00 and $20.00")
public decimal InitialDeposit { get; set; }
```

web.config:

```
<add key="MinBalance" value="5.00"/>
<add key="MaxDeposit" value="20.00"/>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Data Annotation/Validation and dynamic values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2122161/data-annotation-validation-and-dynamic-values)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You will need to create a custom attribute inheriting from `RangeAttribute` and implementing `IClientValidatable`.

```
    public class ConfigRangeAttribute : RangeAttribute, IClientValidatable
    {
        public ConfigRangeAttribute(int Int) :
            base
            (Convert.ToInt32(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["IntMin"]),
             Convert.ToInt32(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["IntMax"])) { }

        public ConfigRangeAttribute(double Double) :
            base
            (Convert.ToDouble(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DoubleMin"]),
             Convert.ToDouble(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DoubleMax"])) 
        {
            _double = true;
        }

        private bool _double = false;

        public override string FormatErrorMessage(string name)
        {
            return String.Format(ErrorMessageString, name, this.Minimum, this.Maximum);
        }

        public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
        {
            var rule = new ModelClientValidationRule
            {
                ErrorMessage = FormatErrorMessage(this.ErrorMessage),
                ValidationType = "range",
            };
            rule.ValidationParameters.Add("min", this.Minimum);
            rule.ValidationParameters.Add("max", this.Maximum);
            yield return rule;
        }

        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            if (value == null)
                return null;

            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(value.ToString()))
                return null;

            if (_double)
            {
                var val = Convert.ToDouble(value);
                if (val >= Convert.ToDouble(this.Minimum) && val <= Convert.ToDouble(this.Maximum))
                    return null;
            }
            else
            {
                var val = Convert.ToInt32(value);
                if (val >= Convert.ToInt32(this.Minimum) && val <= Convert.ToInt32(this.Maximum))
                    return null;
            }

            return new ValidationResult(
                FormatErrorMessage(this.ErrorMessage)
            );
        }
    }
```

Example usage:

```
[ConfigRange(1)]
public int MyInt { get; set; }

[ConfigRange(1.1, ErrorMessage = "This one has gotta be between {1} and {2}!")]
public double MyDouble { get; set; }
```

The first example will return the default error message, and the second will return your custom error message.  Both will use the range values defined in web.config.

Comment: It's great to be appreciated. ;^>  Thanks, and best of luck.

Comment: @rk1962, well, not so much the genius.  I did a quick review of my code, and saw that my server-side validation tests were wrong. :^O  I fixed the incorrect lines in the `IsValid()` function.  Please make sure to apply those changes.

Answer (score 4):

You won't be able to do that in the attribute declaration on the property as the values need to be known at compile time. The easiest way that I could see of doing this would be to derive an attribute class from `RangeAttribute` and set the property values to come from web.config in the derived class. Something like

```
public class RangeFromConfigurationAttribute : RangeAttribute
{
    public RangeFromConfigurationAttribute()
        : base(int.Parse(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MinBalance"]), int.Parse(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MaxDeposit"]))
    {

    }
}
```

May want to come up with a better name though :)

Comment: Thank you so much.  I just created a class with the above code and it did not work.  Am I missing something?

Comment: I'll see if I can put together an example, although counsellorben's code looks like it'd work - http://stackoverflow.com/users/624472/counsellorben

Comment: @Russ Cam, glad someone noticed my contribution.  Though you still got the goodies.  ;)

Comment: Thanks again Russ Cam.  The solution given by counsellorben works great!

Answer (score 1):

Thinking out loud here, but ConfigRange attribute dictates that the config must be present for this to work. Can you not write a static class that would read your values from web.config, app.config or whatever you see fit, and then use that static class in existing range attribute?

```
public static class RangeReader
{
    public static double Range1 
    {
        // Replace this with logic to read from config file
        get { return 20.0d; } 
    }        
}
```

Then annotate your property with:

```
[Range(ConfigReader.Range1, 25.0d)]
```

I know that static classes are bad and there might well be a good reason for not doing this,but I thought i'll give a go.

Comment: I didn't have any compilation errors with a view model, but didn't have a chance to test this out by passing a view model to the view. Can you remember why this didn't work?

Comment: I will try again and let you know the error message.  Thanks!

Comment: I got compilation error: An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type